# How can I play a flv file that is hosted on a remote website?

Tags: html, flash, flv, playback

I'm looking to play a flash video hosted on a remote website. I've tried the following (and profuse google-ing):

In source of page on http://fakesite1.com/player.jsp:

```
<embed src = "FlashPlayer.swf?file=http://fakesite2.net/video.flv" />
```

I can browse to http://fakesite2.net/video.flv and ensure it's there, but the player comes back "movie not loaded" (on right-click) on fakesite1. My initial guess is that this might be some sort of security feature... is it possible to play a video hosted on a remote site?

Comment: Is the issue really about playing remote files, or generally about playing any file? Have you tried playing a local file?

Comment: good call, cris! I tried doing even a local video file and I'm seeing "video not loaded", I think you know more than you are letting on ;)

    <embed src = "FlashPlayer.swf?file=/resources/video/video.flv" />
does not work either.

Comment: i don't know enough about the FlashPlayer you're using, so just a guess: maybe the url to the file needs to be urlencoded?

Comment: The "Movie not loaded" message means the SWF file didn't load, not that the FLV didn't load. Trace your HTTP requests (Chrome's Developer Tools or Firefox's Live HTTP Headers extension) and see what happens to the SWF request.

Comment: @Dai - please post as an answer, that turned out to be the solution and I want to make sure you get the credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message "Movie not loaded" as seen in the context menu of an SWF object in a webpage means that the `.swf` file was not loaded by the browser plugin. The main cause is that that SWF file doesn't exist and the plugin got a 404 error, in which case make sure that the path to the SWF file is correctly set.

Also, the `<embed>` element is obsolete in modern HTML. Use `<object>` instead, as seen below.

Note that various versions of IE (except IE9/10, possibly including IE8) do not support the HTML5 `<object data="" />` element, they prefer the IE4-era `<object clsid="" />` element, so use a conditional comment, like so:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<object width="640" height="480" data="http://mysite.com/myflash.swf" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" >
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object width="640" height="480" data="http://mysite.com/myflash.swf" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your SWF file named exactly "FlashPlayer.swf"?

As far as I know in Windows based systems letter case differences don't matter, however in Unix or Linux based ones it does matter. Your host is probably a Linux one. Try using lower case letters like "flashplayer.swf". Make this a habit with files that will be hosted online all the time. Also no space or special characters, use - or _ to seperate words.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
<embed
   src="player.swf" 
   width="300"
   height="300"
   allowscriptaccess="always"
   allowfullscreen="true"
   id="player1"
   name="player1"
   file="http://fakesite2.net/video.flv"
/>
```